# How to properly restore help window?

Tags: vim

When I save session with opened help window and after exit and restore it with `vim -S Session.vim`, help window restores at place where I was. But it becomes not a *help* window but a regular text file, `^]` not work. If I use `:h <tag_from_that_window>` new help window opened as *help* window and prev "help" window becomes back to *help* (not always).

What wrong?

Vim 7.4 at Linux and Cygwin. `'sessionoptions'` contains "help".

Comment: Vim 7.4 was released height years ago. We are now at version 8.2 so you should probably consider upgrading first.

Comment: I Have not ask is this a bug

Comment: @hobo-mts the reason romainl said that is because this unexpected behaviour could be a bug which has probably already been resolved by newer versions of the program and would save you a lot of hassle anyway

Comment: Workaround: add `setlocal buftype=help nobuflisted` into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim`.